# Where to ask about branding?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For example, I want to create a website with the name Stack Overfailed. However, since it's fresh so I guess that a descriptive URL will encourage people to visit more. I'm thinking about using the domain `getcodefixed.com` for the Stack Overfailed brand name. I want to ask if this is a good approach or not.

Where should I ask this question? I think Webmaster is the closest relevant site for this, since it has the branding tag. However, this question is not about a SEO thing, and that site is a site for technical problem. I'm looking for a site focuses more in marketing aspect.

Comment: I don't think this would work on any site on the network.

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of your site would be?

Comment: This seems like predicting / gauging people's responses to a branding effort, which is essentially subjective. Primarily option-based. So I agree with Pekka - there is no site  on the network where this question would currently fit.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm writing a small program in education and want to sell it. I want to register the domain `learnX.com`, but I don't want to name it as learnX

Comment: @DanBron in the Webmaster, I see some questions are similar to mine. But they ask for the SEO aspect

Comment: @Ooker Correct, because "how to SEO" questions can (often) be answered objectively. I'm sure some marketing questions can too, but as framed, I don't see how the particular question you're amazing about could be answered with anything except opinions.